# ElasticSearch - how to exclude filter from aggregations?

Tags: elasticsearch, facet

I have a filter query with 3 filters: `"query": "iphone", color:5, category:10, brand:25`.

How can I get the number of products in each brand which has `color:5` and `category:10`?

In Solr I did it like:

```
fq={!tag=tag_facet_brand}facet_brand:"564"&facet.field={!ex=tag_facet_brand}facet_brand
```

How can I exclude 1 filter from the aggregation context? (I can't use global, because I lose `query:iphone`, and I can't use post_filter - because of performance).

Comment: Yes, after some time in production and experiments, solution with "global": {}, - is the best possibility which i found. It works not super fast, but with cache it has acceptable performance.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12014571/490018.

Answer (score 9):

We are just moving from SOLR and we are facing the same issue.

You could try global bucket then add a [query filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-filter.html) for each bucket :

```
"filter" : {
            "query" : {
                "query_string" : {
                    "query" : "iPhone"
                }
            }
        }
```

You should end with something like :

```
{
    "size": 10,
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "iphone"
        }
    },
    "filter": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "brand": "564"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "color": "5"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "category": "10"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "all": {
            "global": {},
            "aggs": {
                "keyword": {
                    "filter": {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": [
                                {
                                    "query": {
                                        "query_string": {
                                            "query": "iphone"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "term": {
                                        "color": "5"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "term": {
                                        "category": "10"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "brand": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "brand"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "global": {}, - is not good in this case because i have 20 aggs, so request size is growing extremely and it's not developer friendly. DRY principle must be in request too.

Comment: We also have lots of aggs. 
We remain DRY, but in the code generating the request...
foreach agg, you add every filter except the one related to the agg.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Lionel Sengkouvanh answer, here's the equivalent with the java API:

```
SearchRequestBuilder request = client
  .prepareSearch(INDEX_NAME)
  .setQuery(theQuery)
  ...
  .addAggregation(
     AggregationBuilders.global("all").subAggregation(      
       AggregationBuilders.filter("keyword").filter(filter).subAggregation(
         AggregationBuilders.terms("brand").field("brand")  
       )
     )
  );
```